# Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id while scan qr using qr_flutter libary

Tags: flutter, elasticsearch

Error stack trace:

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id [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] is too long, must be no longer than 512 bytes but was: 992; at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:15) at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.validate(IndexRequest.java:255) at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy.exec

Any solutions would be much helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error message is very clear, Elasticsearch doesn't allow `_id` to be greater than 512 bytes but you sent 992 byte long `_id`, change it to smaller size to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Amit for clarifying the cause, yet not getting how to validate it, where I should write a condition like that,  I am reading the barcode value, do I need to evalute there, if yes, would you pls assist me with sample? FYI, coding lang is dart and error faced for both android and iOS platform. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nira, simplest solution is, don't generate these ids and than Elasticsearch will generate it itself